# SQL UTF-8 encoding printing �

Tags: php, html, sql, encoding, utf-8

am working on SQL databases that will have content in different languages, Spanish, Portuguese, English, Chinese ... etc. I have some content already on the database in Spanish and I have already setup the collation settings to `utf8_general_ci` but for some reason it still print this symbol "�". I guess is a character that has not been encoded.

This is what I did for the HTML5 code. According to [W3SCHOOLS](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_utf8.asp) the default character encoding in HTML-5 is UTF-8, so I tried with the `charset` and with out it.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
   </head>
   <body>
      <?php
          // PRINT'S CONTENT FROM DB
      ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Below is my SQL database side.

```
ALTER TABLE `table` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Is there anything I am missing or anything I haven't done?

Comment: Consult http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Thank you Fred, I thought I wouldn't need `mysql_set_charset` to be configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the function [mysql_set_charset](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-set-charset.php)

Answer (score 1):

**Please change the setting from the following folder php/mysql setup:**

```
// ***notice "utf8", without dash, this is a mysql encoding***
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```